# PAYMENT accepted with European Card, REFUSED with Latin America card

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've successfully integrated the paypal buttons in my website. with the REST API + PHP :D
I live in France and I'm from Colombia, so I did some tests with my real french card and transactions were successful, but with cards from Colombia, transactions are always refused. I called my Colombian's bank and there is nothing wrong. In DevTools Console I got this: xo_inline_guest_unhandled_error

```
`handledErrors: Array(0), unhandledErrors: Array(1), inline_guest_version: '2.19.3', timestamp:   1682207616123, windowID: '110c161eca'`
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work overseas? :(

I tried changing the 'device': EUR -> COP , but COP is not supported.
I tried changing price to avoid decimals: 1.00 to 1.
I tried changing the language in the script tag: fr_FR to es_CO.
I tried with 2 french credit cards and payment was successfull! (even with a price of 0.2 EUR)
I tried with 4 colombian credit cards and I always have the same error.
I tried putting a higher price: 1 EUR to 10 EUR (with and without decimals)

Full console object returned when transaction refused:

```
{
    "handledErrors": [],
    "unhandledErrors": [
        {
            "message": "TRANSACTION_REFUSED",
            "path": [
                "approveGuestPaymentWithCreditCard"
            ],
            "checkpoints": [
                "createCheckoutSession"
            ],
            "meta": {},
            "errorData": {
                "step_up_context": {}
            },
            "contingency": true,
            "statusCode": 200
        }
    ],
    "inline_guest_version": "2.19.3",
    "timestamp": 1682323069949,
    "windowID": "d37c79083f",
    "pageID": "aff971fc33",
    "referer": "www.paypal.com",
    "host": "www.paypal.com",
    "path": "/smart/card-fields",
    "env": "production",
    "country": "CO",
    "lang": "es",
    "uid": "uid_6b8882c193_mdc6nty6mju",
    "ver": "2.19.3"
}
```

Comment: When capturing an order that is "refused", what is the response?

Answer (score 0):

Absent relevant technical details (which there likely aren't any for this case), the situation here is that in the second case the transaction was denied, intentionally by PayPal and there is no technical nor programming issue. In these situations the intended payer/buyer can contact PayPal with any questions, https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contactus .

Comment: If you search for TRANSACTION_REFUSED you'll find a number of answers saying it's a normal PayPal decline. Not a programming nor technical issue